# Closure of a set in a "Topology of finite complement"

Tags: general-topology, compactness, axiom-of-choice

Well, I was reading [this article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm37/fm3716.pdf) by Kelley and when reached the point where he say that $X_a$ is closed in $Y_a$ I had to stop, probably mine is just a stupid misunderstand but can't figure out how to prove that $X_a$ is closed.

Another problem: if $X_a$ is closed than $Y_a-X_a$ has to be open, thuse $Y_a-(Y_a-X_a)$ finite, and we picked some random space $X_a$ so that is not generally true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a typo (or a small mistake, if you prefer), and the proof goes along just fine if you also require that $\{\Lambda\}$ is open in each $X_a$. The space is still compact.

You can find the same proof, minus the typo, on the Wikipedia page of [the Tychonoff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_axiom_of_choice_from_Tychonoff.27s_theorem).